# How to get and send messages asynchronously from one websocket client to antoher

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

I need to establish connection between client websocket threw my backend on spring java to another websocket where my backend is a client, I established connection as client but can't figure out how to send it back as soon as my client send me message,

My Client Endpoint works as I need

```
    @Service
@ClientEndpoint
public class ClientEndpoint {

    Session userSession = null;

    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    public WbsClientEndpoint(@Value("${url}") String url) {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, new URI(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
        System.out.println("opening web socket");
        this.userSession = userSession;
    }
    
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("closing web socket");
        this.userSession = null;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        if (this.messageHandler != null) {
            this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
        }
    }
    
    public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
    }
    
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
    }
    
    public interface MessageHandler {
        void handleMessage(String message);
    }
}
```

and example of method when I send my message as client, it does what I need but now I only printing the message cause cannot connect it to my message handler:

```
@Override
    public void addDevice(DeviceTransfer deviceTransfer) {
        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(message -> {
            System.out.println("Response: " + message);

        });
        clientEndPoint.sendMessage(JSON.toJSONString(deviceTransfer));
    }
```

Also I wrote a websockethandler for messages that comes to my backend:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("New Text Message Received" + message + " ___ " + session);
        String clientMessage = message.getPayload();

        if (clientMessage.startsWith("/addDevice")) {
           //Here I don't know how to send this clientMessage and wait for result from my addDevice method to return it back
        }
    } 
}
```

And I need to connect both of the realizations to establish connection in real time.
When client sends message to me I must send this message to another server as client.

My client code on JavaScript as example, when I press button it establish connection to my web socket and send my message:

```
const connectBtn = document.getElementById('connect');
        if (connectBtn) {
            connectBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                window.socket1 = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081/ws");

                socket1.onopen = function(e) {
                    console.log("[open]");
                   
                    socket1.send(JSON.stringify({"command": "subscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"/topic/addDevice\"}"}))
                };

                socket1.onmessage = function(event) {


                    console.log(`[message]: ${event.data}`);
                };

                socket1.onclose = function(event) {
                    if (event.wasClean) {
                        console.log(`[close],code=${event.code}reason=${event.reason}`);
                    } else {
                      
                        console.log('[close]');
                    }
                };

                socket1.onerror = function(error) {
                    console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
                };
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you need to keep track of your `ClientEndpoint` instances:

```java
public class ClientEndpoint {

    private HashSet<ClientEndpoint> endpoints = new HashSet<>();
    // or perhaps a HashMap using `userSession.id` or similar
    private HashMap<string, ClientEndpoint> userToEndpoint = new HahsMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
        System.out.println("opening web socket");
        this.userSession = userSession;
        this.endpoints.add(this);
        this.userToEndpoint.put(userSession.id, this);
    }
    
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("closing web socket");
        this.endpoints.remove(this);
        this.userToEndpoint.delete(userSession.id);
        this.userSession = null;
    }
    
}
```

You can use `endpoints`/`userToEndpoint` to find all connected clients, perhaps filter by which rooms they're in (I assume that's what you're trying to accomplish with that `subscribe` command), and do whatever you want with that information. E.g. a broadcast  to everyone except the sender:

```java
for (ClientEnpoint endpoint : this.endpoints) {
    if (endpoint == sender) continue; // Don't send to sender
    endpoint.sendMessage("message");
}
```